# Scrapy : create folder structure out of downloaded images based on the url from which images are being downloaded

Tags: python, scrapy

I have an array of links that define the structure of a website. While downloading images from these links, I want to simultaneously place the downloaded images in a folder structure similar to the website structure, and not just rename it (as answered in [Scrapy image download how to use custom filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194041/scrapy-image-download-how-to-use-custom-filename))

My code for the same is like this:

```
class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    """Custom image pipeline to rename images as they are being downloaded"""
    page_url=None
    def image_key(self, url):
        page_url=self.page_url
        image_guid = url.split('/')[-1]
        return '%s/%s/%s' % (page_url,image_guid.split('_')[0],image_guid)

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        #http://store.abc.com/b/n/s/m
        os.system('mkdir '+item['sku'][0].encode('ascii','ignore'))
        self.page_url = urlparse(item['start_url']).path #I store the parent page's url in start_url Field
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield Request(image_url)
```

It creates the required folder structure but when I go into the folders in deapth, I see that the files have been misplaced in the folders.

I'm suspecting that it is happening because the "get_media_requests" and "image_key" functions might be executing asynchronously hence the value of "page_url" changes before it is used by the "image_key" function.

Comment: would calculating the path in the spider and passing path as a item attribute be more accurate?

Comment: @dm03514 I have the required path as an item attribute but, I'm not able to access the "item" object inside the "image_key" function

Comment: @GauravToshniwal i have doubt . i can't see any code showing folder is being created , any idea on how internals works ?

Comment: @igaurav, updated the same in the code. Sorry, Internals of which part?

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right that asynchronous Item processing prevents using class variables via `self` within the pipeline.  You will have to store your path in each Request and override a few more methods (untested):

```
def image_key(self, url, page_url):
    image_guid = url.split('/')[-1]
    return '%s/%s/%s' % (page_url, image_guid.split('_')[0], image_guid)

def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
    for image_url in item['image_urls']:
        yield Request(image_url, meta=dict(page_url=urlparse(item['start_url']).path))

def get_images(self, response, request, info):
    key = self.image_key(request.url, request.meta.get('page_url'))
    ...

def media_to_download(self, request, info):
    ...
    key = self.image_key(request.url, request.meta.get('page_url'))
    ...

def media_downloaded(self, response, request, info):
    ...
    try:
        key = self.image_key(request.url, request.meta.get('page_url'))
    ...
```

Comment: thank for solution. i have tested it so far so good! All the images within same item or same request will be stored in same path (folder).

Comment: @steven-almeroth , where is creation folder shown in code ? can you explain a bit .

Comment: `image_key()` returns the folder name, it can be anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

This scrapy pipeline extension provides an easy way to store downloaded files into a folder tree.

You have to install it:

```sh
pip install scrapy_folder_tree
```

and then, add the pipeline on your configuration:

```py
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'scrapy_folder_tree.ImagesHashTreePipeline': 300
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of [scrapy-folder-tree](https://github.com/sp1thas/scrapy-folder-tree)