# Scrapy: How to change the image name

Tags: scrapy

I'm using scrapy to do a project.
I got the image name and image url in html, how can I name this image with that name instead of the hash name?

I got this url: http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/104/Purple/v4/55/35/20/55352022-0aba-260b-76ed-314eacd8c1fc/mzm.zqqzrdix.175x175-75.jpg
and it's name: iBook
I want my scrapy to download this picture and rename it with iBook.

Comment: Could you post your spider code and the url you're crawling (I'm guessing it's the Apple website) so that we take a look at what you've got so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrapy: customize Image pipeline with renaming defualt image name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081997/scrapy-customize-image-pipeline-with-renaming-defualt-image-name)

Answer (score 6):

You have to use the Images pipeline and something like this

```
class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def image_key(self, url):
        image_guid = url.split('/')[-1]
        return 'full/%s' % (image_guid)
```

It will use the original image name. For custom filename use something like

`return 'ibook.jpg'` But it will overwrite all the images with same file. be careful

get some more ideas from this [Scrapy image download how to use custom filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194041/scrapy-image-download-how-to-use-custom-filename?rq=1)