# Change Naming Convention for Images Pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy

*Update*

This is embarrassing, but it turned out that the problem with my original pipeline was that I'd forgotten to activate it in my settings. eLRuLL was right anyway, though.

---

I'm at the stage where I have a working spider that can consistently retrieve the information I'm interested in and push it out in the format I want. My—hopefully—final stumbling block is applying a more reasonable naming convention to the files saved by my images pipeline. The SHA1 hash works, but I find it really unpleasant to work with.

I'm having trouble interpreting the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html) to figure out how to change the naming system, and I didn't have any luck blindly applying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081997/scrapy-customize-image-pipeline-with-renaming-defualt-image-name) solution. In the course of my scrape, I'm already pulling down a unique identifier for each page; I'd like to use it to name the images, since there's only one per page.

The image pipeline also doesn't seem to respect the `fields_to_export` section of my pipeline. I'd like to suppress the image urls to give myself a cleaner, more readable output. If anyone has an idea how to do that, I'd be very grateful.

The unique identifier that it'd like to pull out of my parse is `CatalogRecord.add_xpath('accession', './/dd[@class="accession"]/text()')`. You'll find my spider and my pipelines below.

Spider:

```
URL = "http://www.nga.gov/content/ngaweb/Collection/art-object-page.%d"
starting_number = 1315
number_of_pages = 1311
class NGASpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'ngamedallions'
    allowed_domains = ['nga.gov']
    start_urls = [URL % i + '.html' for i in range (starting_number, number_of_pages, -1)]
    rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('art-object-page.*','objects/*')),callback='parse_CatalogRecord',
follow=True
),)



    def parse_CatalogRecord(self, response):
        CatalogRecord = ItemLoader(item=NgamedallionsItem(), response=response)
        CatalogRecord.default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
        CatalogRecord.image_urls_out = scrapy.loader.processors.Identity()
        keywords = "reverse|obverse and (medal|medallion)"
        notkey = "Image Not Available"
        n = re.compile('.*(%s).*' % notkey, re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE|re.UNICODE)
        r = re.compile('.*(%s).*' % keywords, re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE|re.UNICODE)
        if not n.search(response.body_as_unicode()):
            if r.search(response.body_as_unicode()):
                CatalogRecord.add_xpath('title', './/dl[@class="artwork-details"]/dt[@class="title"]/text()')
                CatalogRecord.add_xpath('accession', './/dd[@class="accession"]/text()')
                CatalogRecord.add_xpath('inscription', './/div[@id="inscription"]/p/text()', Join(), re='[A-Z]+')
                CatalogRecord.add_xpath('image_urls', './/img[@class="mainImg"]/@src')
                CatalogRecord.add_xpath('date', './/dt[@class="title"]', re='(\d+-\d+)')

                return CatalogRecord.load_item()
```

Pipelines:

```
class NgamedallionsPipeline(object):
  def __init__(self):
     self.files = {}

  @classmethod
  def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    pipeline = cls()
    crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
    crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
    return pipeline

  def spider_opened(self, spider):
    file = open('%s_items.csv' % spider.name, 'w+b')
    self.files[spider] = file
    self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(file)
    self.exporter.fields_to_export = ['accession', 'title', 'date', 'inscription']
    self.exporter.start_exporting()

  def spider_closed(self, spider):
    self.exporter.finish_exporting()
    file = self.files.pop(spider)
    file.close()

  def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.exporter.export_item(item)
    return item
```

Comment: about the `fields_to_export`, please try passing the list on the constructor: `CsvItemExporter(file, fields_to_export=['accesion',...])`

Comment: No luck. I'm getting the same output as before. The items.csv that I produce gives me, in order: inscription, title, accession, image_urls, images, and date.
Could part of the problem be some conflict the image pipeline, which has its own mechanics tucked away behind the scenes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding renaming the images written to disk, here's one way to do it:

1. add something in `meta` for the images `Request` generated by the pipeline by overriding `get_media_requests()`
2. override `file_path()` and use that info from `meta`

Example custom `ImagesPipeline`:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline


class NgaImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        # use 'accession' as name for the image when it's downloaded
        return [scrapy.Request(x, meta={'image_name': item["accession"]})
                for x in item.get('image_urls', [])]

    # write in current folder using the name we chose before
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        return '%s.jpg' % request.meta['image_name']
```

Regarding exported fields, the suggestion from @eLRuLL worked for me:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter


class NgaCsvPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.files = {}

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        ofile = open('%s_items.csv' % spider.name, 'w+b')
        self.files[spider] = ofile
        self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(ofile,
            fields_to_export = ['accession', 'title', 'date', 'inscription'])
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        ofile = self.files.pop(spider)
        ofile.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```

Comment: Your custom image pipeline worked perfectly. Thank you!