# Scrapy Image Pipeline: How to rename images?

Tags: image, python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I've a spider which fetches both the data and images. I want to rename the images with the respective 'title' which i'm fetching.

Following is my code:

**spider1.py**

```
from imageToFileSystemCheck.items import ImagetofilesystemcheckItem
import scrapy

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = 'imagecheck'

    def start_requests(self):

        searchterms=['keyword1','keyword2',]
        for item in searchterms:
                yield scrapy.Request('http://www.example.com/s?=%s' % item,callback=self.parse, meta={'item': item})

    def parse(self,response):
        start_urls=[]
        item = response.meta.get('item')
        for i in range(0,2):
            link=str(response.css("div.tt a.chek::attr(href)")[i].extract())
            start_urls.append(link)

        for url in start_urls:
            print(url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_info ,meta={'item': item})

    def parse_info(self, response):
        url=response.url
        title=str(response.xpath('//*[@id="Title"]/text()').extract_first())
        img_url_1=response.xpath("//img[@id='images']/@src").extract_first()

        scraped_info = {
            'url' : url,
            'title' : title,
            'image_urls': [img_url_1]
        }

        yield scraped_info
```

**items.py**

```
import scrapy


class ImagetofilesystemcheckItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

**pipelines.py**

```
class ImagetofilesystemcheckPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item
```

**settings.py**

```
BOT_NAME = 'imageToFileSystemCheck'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['imageToFileSystemCheck.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'imageToFileSystemCheck.spiders'

ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
IMAGES_STORE = '/home/imageToFileSystemCheck/images/'


ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
```

Can you please help me with the required changes so that scrapy could save the scraped images in the **'title'.jpg** format where title is scraped by the spider?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrapy: customize Image pipeline with renaming defualt image name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081997/scrapy-customize-image-pipeline-with-renaming-defualt-image-name)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Spider like this

```
class ShopeeSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    _TEMP_IMAGES_STORE = "/home/crawler/scrapers/images"


    custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
            'coszi.pipelines.CustomImagePipeline': 400,
        }
         "IMAGES_STORE": _TEMP_IMAGES_STORE
    }


    def parse(self, response):

        data = {}

        data['images'] = {"image_link_here": "image_name_here"}
```

Then your pipelines.py should be like this

```
class CustomImagePipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        if 'images' in item:
            for image_url, img_name in item['images'].iteritems():

                if os.path.exists(os.path.join(item['images_path'], img_name)) == False:
                    request = scrapy.Request(url=image_url)
                    request.meta['img_name'] = img_name
                    request.meta['this_prod_img_folder'] = item['img_name_here']
                    request.dont_filter = True
                    yield request

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        return os.path.join(info.spider.CRAWLER_IMAGES_STORE, request.meta['this_prod_img_folder'], request.meta['img_name'])
```