# Scrapy file download using custom path based on item

Tags: python, scrapy

what I would like to do is pretty basic I think but I couldn't find a way to implement it.

I am trying to use the [FilesPipeline](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.0/scrapy/pipelines/files.py#L85) in scrapy in order to download a file (ex. Image1.jpg) and save it on a path relative to the item which placed that request in the first place (ex. item.name).

---

It is pretty similar with this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194041/scrapy-image-download-how-to-use-custom-filename), though I want to pass as an argument the item.name or item.something field, in order to save each file in a custom path depending on the item.name.

The path is defined in the `persist_file` function, but that function does not have access to the item itself, just the file request and response.

> ```
> def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
>     return [Request(x) for x in item.get(self.FILES_URLS_FIELD, [])]
> ```
>
> I can also see above, that the request is made here in order to process the files into the pipeline, but is there a way to pass an extra argument in order to later use it on the `file_downloaded` and afterwards on `persist_file`  function?

As a final solution, it would be pretty simple to rename/move the file after it has been downloaded in one of the following pipelines but it seems sloppy, isn't it?

I am using the code implemented [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.0/scrapy/pipelines/files.py#L85) as a custom pipeline.

Can anyone help please?
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Create your own pipeline (inherited from `FilesPipeline`) overriding the `process_item` method of the pipeline, to pass the current item to the other functions

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    info = self.spiderinfo
    requests = arg_to_iter(self.get_media_requests(item, info))
    dlist = [self._process_request(r, info, item) for r in requests]
    dfd = DeferredList(dlist, consumeErrors=1)
    return dfd.addCallback(self.item_completed, item, info)
```

then you need to override `_process_request` and keep passing the item argument to use it for when creating the file path.