# Scrapy file download how to use custom filename

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

For my [scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/index.html) project I'm currently using the [FilesPipeline](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline). The downloaded files are stored with a SHA1 hash of their URLs as the file names.

```
[(True,
  {'checksum': '2b00042f7481c7b056c4b410d28f33cf',
   'path': 'full/0a79c461a4062ac383dc4fade7bc09f1384a3910.jpg',
   'url': 'http://www.example.com/files/product1.pdf'}),
 (False,
  Failure(...))]
```

**How can I store the files using my custom file names instead?**

In the example above, I would want the file name being *"product1_0a79c461a4062ac383dc4fade7bc09f1384a3910.pdf"* so I keep uniqueness but make the file name visible.

As a starting point, I explored the `pipelines.py` of my project without much success.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.images import FilesPipeline
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class MyFilesPipeline(FilesPipeline):

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        return request.meta.get('filename','')

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        file_url = item['file_url']
        meta = {'filename': item['name']}
        yield Request(url=file_url, meta=meta)
```

with the inclusion of this parameter in my `settings.py`

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    #'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 300
    'io_spider.pipelines.MyFilesPipeline': 200
}
```

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194041/scrapy-image-download-how-to-use-custom-filename/22263951) has been asked but it does target images and not files.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`file_path` should return the path to your file. In your code, `file_path` returns `item['name']` and that will be your file's path. Note that by default `file_path` [calculates SHA1 hashes](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/pipelines/files.py#L464). So your method should be something like this:

```
def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
    original_path = super(MyFilesPipeline, self).file_path(request, response=None, info=None)
    sha1_and_extension = original_path.split('/')[1] # delete 'full/' from the path
    return request.meta.get('filename','') + "_" + sha1_and_extension
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the help I was expecting - just one small issue with your code in my context, the last like concatenate a list with a string so I had to explicitly select the first item in the list `return request.meta.get('filename','')[0] + "_" + sha1_and_extension`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this `file_path` method:

```
def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
    url = request if not isinstance(request, Request) else request.url
    media_guid = hashlib.sha1(to_bytes(url)).hexdigest()
    path, media_ext = os.path.splitext(url)
    media_name = os.path.split(path)[1]
    return '%s_%s%s' % (media_name, media_guid, media_ext)
```

(note: this is untested code)