# Python/Scrapy: Custom pipeline has no effect / download files with custom filename

Tags: python, scrapy

This is a follow-up question to my [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54790699/how-to-download-pdf-files-with-python-scrapy-using-the-files-pipeline).
I want to download PDFs and save them on harddisk with custom filename.

For the custom filename I tried this code in my `pipelines.py` according to this [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47039866/508311):

```py
class PrangerPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        original_path = super(PrangerPipeline, self).file_path(request, response=None, info=None)
        sha1_and_extension = original_path.split('/')[1] # delete 'full/' from the path
        return request.meta.get('filename','') + "_" + sha1_and_extension

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        file_url = item['file_url']
        meta = {'filename': item['name']}
        yield Request(url=file_url, meta=meta)
```

In my `settings.py` I have:

```python
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'pranger.pipelines.PrangerPipeline': 1,
    'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 2,
}
```

But the files keep being saved only with their SHA1-hash, for example: a8569143c987cdd43dd1f6d9a6f98b7aa6fbc284.PDF. So my custom `file_path` function seems not to be used by Scrapy.

When I comment out the line

```py
'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 2,
```

nothing will be downloaded.

I am confused...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is your custom pipeline is not a real file pipeline, therefore it does nothing. You need to *subclass* the original `FilesPipeline` and then use only `PrangerPipeline` in the settings.

For example:

`pipelines.py`:

```
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline

class PrangerPipeline(FilesPipeline):

    # Don't override process_item. The parent class handles it.

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        # ...

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        # ...
```

`settings.py`:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'pranger.pipelines.PrangerPipeline': 1,
}
```

Refer to my examples using `ImagesPipeline` here:

[Unable to rename downloaded images through pipelines without the usage of item.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54737465/unable-to-rename-downloaded-images-through-pipelines-without-the-usage-of-item-p/54741148#54741148)

[Trouble renaming downloaded images in a customized manner through pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54773331/trouble-renaming-downloaded-images-in-a-customized-manner-through-pipelines/54781395#54781395)

Comment: My mistake was to override `process_item` by a do-nothing implementation. +1 for mentioning that as a comment in the code.